Based on only one of the two
The list of words you see below have been alphabetically sorted. They are not the only words that could've been in the list (in fact there are many more, I just chose these).
 Advisor
 Analysing
 Beforehand 
 Best
 Classy
 Eight
 Ellipse 
 Feet
 Heated
 Hinting
 Lengths
 Orient
 Shake
 Turfskiing
 Unlikelihood
 Withholder
           
        .  ..  ... ....
  
    .  [4] [4] [2] [10]
   ..  [1] [1] [6] [2]
  ...  [3] [5] [2] [5]
 ....  [4] [4] [2] [10...]


What's being combined here?

What is being combined here are

 THE DOT ONLY LETTERS of the morse code!

Reason

 Each word has an adjacent pair of dot only letters from the morse code within them… The letters are signified by the dots on the top and left hand side of the grid (E,I,S,H) in order.

So

 Sort the words out like so on the 4x4 grid based on the combination of the letter pair contained within them and then extract the letters using its corresponding number to get THE DOT ONLY LETTER(S in morse)


Title

 There are no dashes involved here!


Nice job! This is it. I didn't get why the (T), other than that everything looks good.

I don't get why the last answer is S, and not E or I or H, since all of them use dots only.

@ArturoVialArqueros I used three dots (after the last 10) and three dots correspond to S

Ooooh, I got tricked into thinking it was an ellipsis. Nice catch!
